2d diffusion equation with boundary conditions: problem with probability conservation
Version: Mathematica 12
I want to numerically solve the 2d diffusion equation $\partial_t u(x,y,t) = D\Big( \partial_x^2 u(x,y,t)+ \partial_y^2 u(x,y,t) \Big)$ over some region with specific boundary conditions. Consider a square, which is centered around the origin and has an area of $A = 2x_{max}\cdot 2y_{max}$, and cut out a unit-circle, which is smaller than the square.

On the outer boundary of the square I want to enforce periodic boundary conditions $u(-x_{max},y,t) = u(x_{max},y,t), u(,x-y_{max},t) = u(x,y_{max},t)$, whereas on the inner boundary, I want to enforce no-flux boundary conditions $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\nabla}u(x,y,t) = 0$.
Here is my code:
ClearAll;

(*Define relevant parameters*)
diffusionCoefficient = 1.;

(*Define relevant parameters for the simulation/simulation volume*)
tmax = 10.00;
xmax = 3.0;
ymax = 3.0;

(*Define initial conditions*)
sigmaXY = 0.2;
initialCondition = u[x, y, 0] == Exp[-((x + 2)^2)/(2. sigmaXY^2)]/(sigmaXY Sqrt[
    2. Pi]) Exp[-(y^2)/(2. sigmaXY^2)]/(sigmaXY Sqrt[2. Pi]);

(*Define boundary conditions*)
spatialBoundaryConditions = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, t], x == -xmax, Function[x, x + {2 xmax, 0}]], 
                             PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y, t], y == -ymax, Function[y, y + {0, 2 ymax}]]};

(*Define all necessary terms for the diffusion equation*)
spatialDiffusionTerm = diffusionCoefficient (D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);
diffusionEquation = D[u[x, y, t], t] - spatialDiffusionTerm == 0;

(*Construct mesh*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{inner = Disk[{1, 0}, 1.0], outer = Rectangle[{-xmax, -ymax}, {xmax, ymax}]},
     (mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[outer, inner], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.05, ImproveBoundaryPosition -> Automatic])["Wireframe"]]

(*Actually solve the diffusion equation*)
sol = NDSolve[{diffusionEquation, initialCondition, spatialBoundaryConditions}, 
              u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, {t, 0, tmax}, 
              Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];

(*Define some functions for plotting and analysis purposes*)
g[x_, y_] := Evaluate[u[x, y, 10.] /. sol];
Plot3D[Evaluate[g[x, y]], {x, -xmax, xmax}, {y, -ymax, ymax}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "h"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 20]

f[x_, y_, t_] := Evaluate[u[x, y, t] /. sol];
h[t_] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, t], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
Plot[h[t], {t, 0, tmax}, AxesLabel -> {t, f[t]}]

If I plot the result of NDSolve at $t=10$, I get the following solution:

This looks quite promising, however plotting the total probability $h(t)$ reveals that the total probability is not conserved, which should be the case!

So apparently there is something wrong. I've replaced the periodic boundary conditions on the outer boundary of the square with no-flux boundary conditions and the total probability is conserved. However I can't spot the mistake I've made, so any help would be appreciated.

I think that probability should not be conserved in your case since the periodic conditions on the outer boundary enable it to flow out from the domain. I made an attempt to check it, but Mma warned of an error at the NDSolve step. To force the probability conservation, one needs either to balance the boundary fluxes or use the no-flux boundary conditions also at the outer boundary.
